# what is the correct navigation sequence? because tabbars can't dissapear when the switch contains stack, and the switch is child of bottomtabnavigator

Tags: javascript, react-native, authentication, react-navigation

I'm making react native applications, where my application is like a marketplace application. My app has bottom tab navigation as root navigation with 5 tabs, and the fifth tab contains a switchNavigator to authenticate if the user has successfully logged in / register then will switch to the profileStack and stay in loginStack when not logged in. When I want to set bottomTabNavigator tabbat visibility to disappear when the screen stack of profileStack > 0, it means that the tabbar bottomTabNavigator is only visible on the main profile page and does not appear on the editprofile page, but with the switchNavigator inside the bottomTabNavigator, the tabbar continues to appear until the editprofile page

my app using lib version:
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.6",
"react-navigation": "^3.3.2"

```
import {createStackNavigator, createMaterialTopTabNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
    LogIn :{screen: LogIn, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}) },
    Register :{screen: Register, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}) },
    RegisterPassword :{screen: RegisterPassword, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}) }
},{
    initialRouteName: 'LogIn'
})

LoginStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    let tabBarVisible = true;
    if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
      tabBarVisible = false;
    }

    return {
      tabBarVisible,
    };
};

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
    Profile :{screen: Profile, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}) },
    MyPoint :{screen: MyPoint, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}) },
    EditProfileMenu :{screen: EditProfileMenu, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}) },
    EditProfile :{screen: EditProfile, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}) },
    ProfileAddress :{screen: ProfileAddress, navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({header: null}) }
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Profile'
})

ProfileStack.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    let tabBarVisible = true;
    if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
      tabBarVisible = false;
    }

    return {
      tabBarVisible,
    };
};

const AuthSwitch = createSwitchNavigator({
    AuthChecker: { screen: AuthChecker, 
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({title: 'AuthChecker'}) },
    LoginStack: { screen: LoginStack},
    ProfileStack: { screen: ProfileStack}
},{
    initialRouteName: 'AuthChecker'
})

AuthSwitch.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    let tabBarVisible = true;
    if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
      tabBarVisible = false;
    }

    return {
      tabBarVisible,
    };
};

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home :{screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Home",
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                // <Ionicons name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24} />
                focused ?
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/home_active.png')} style={{width:23, height:23}} />
                : <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/home.png')} style={{width:23, height:23}} />
            )
        }},
    FastShop :{screen: FastShopStack,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Fast Shop",
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                // <Ionicons name="ios-cart" color={tintColor} size={24} />
                focused ?
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/fast_shop_active.png')} style={{width:23, height:23}} />
                : <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/fast_shop.png')} style={{width:23, height:23}} />
            )
        }},
    MyOrder :{screen: MyOrderStack,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "My Order",
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                // <Ionicons name="ios-list-box" color={tintColor} size={24} />
                focused ?
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/myorder_active.png')} style={{width:23, height:23}} />
                : <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/myorder.png')} style={{width:23, height:23}} />
            )
        }},
    Inbox :{screen: Inbox,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Inbox",
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                // <Ionicons name="ios-chatbubbles" color={tintColor} size={24} />
                focused ?
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/inbox_active.png')} style={{width:28, height:23}} />
                : <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/inbox.png')} style={{width:28, height:23}} />
            )
        }},
    Account :{screen: AuthSwitch,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: "Account",
            tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                // <Ionicons name="ios-contact" color={tintColor} size={24} />
                focused ?
                <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/akun_active.png')} style={{width:23, height:23}} />
                : <Image source={require('../assets/images/nav/akun.png')} style={{width:23, height:23}} />
            )
        }},
    },{
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        tabBarOptions: {
            style: {
             backgroundColor: '#FFF',
             height:50
            },
            activeTintColor: '#2EB499',
            inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 10,
              },
          }
    }
);

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

i expect the tabbar of profileStack and loginStack only appear only on Profile and Login initialRoute page